# In TypeScript, is it possible to declare an object where property names all belong to a certain enum?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum and classes:

```
export enum AnimalTypes {
  MONKEY = 'MONKEY',
  HORSE = 'HORSE',
  DOG = 'DOG',
}

export abstract class Animal {}
export class Monkey extends Animal {}
export class Horse extends Animal {}
export class Dog extends Animal {}
```

Now I want to use an object as a hashmap to map these enum types to certain values:

```
const animalMapper = {
  [AnimalTypes.MONKEY] = new Monkey();
  [AnimalTypes.HORSE] = new Horse();
  [AnimalTypes.DOG] = new Dog();
}
```

However, I want animalMapper to be an interface of a certain type. What would be the type of an object where all property names are equal to that of a given Enum? Something like:

```
export interface AnimalMapper {
  [AnimalTypes]: Animal
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like the built in [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility type:

```
type AnimalMapper = Record<AnimalTypes, Animal>;
```

Then the following would work:

```
const animalMapper: AnimalMapper = {
    [AnimalTypes.MONKEY]: new Monkey(),
    [AnimalTypes.HORSE]: new Horse(),
    [AnimalTypes.DOG]: new Dog()
}
```

while these are errors:

```
const badAnimalMapper: AnimalMapper = {
    [AnimalTypes.MONKEY]: new Monkey(),
    [AnimalTypes.HORSE]: new Horse(),
    [AnimalTypes.DOG]: new Dog(),
    "wombat": new Animal() // error, wombat is an extra property
}

const alsoBadAnimalMapper: AnimalMapper = { // error, missing HORSE
    [AnimalTypes.MONKEY]: new Monkey(),
    [AnimalTypes.HORSE]: new Horse(),
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwIKIJaoIYA2AKgJ5jADOcA3gFBwNwCyA8gHIDSAogJpwC8cAOStOvIQBp6jABIsASgGUuA4XKVdJ0hgBEWAcVVC9+oXFoBfWrQDGBPBSpZchGnDwB+AFxwKMKNiIAOZwVnYOVEwQiADWwCQIIDBIACZOOPgEbqjevv6BIWH2jnAy0BTAicmIaZgZrtRwABa5fgHBobbFVDoQIaDVtc6Zbimt+R1WtDBklcOETHhg5FCq8sA20CkAPPPEsxQSdS4EAHwA3NabiH7u9QSLy8BQPnuPK6p0jHAA2nuk5AoADpRNweABdHyIYAAd2Y0TiJAAFABKKTfP73AGUIHqZSQuDQuFlKAVVHoxiYk7Y4EmAlEuC9ILkyxXaK3ABGeBSbyWK1e93ez0+2l+-wOIPYYPpsPhsXiLIx4sBuIU+KhspJZLRoqpmRpQLpGrhTMVjAARDCIKguTBzcbjplUXAAPQuhBQKDQI5Wm14eDYKh4RBVKB4OBgL0rGas2zs+CECgQABC3N5TxejoWfOFgkabo9XqgR1QgYoBVKaq4uuVONBvBlcKi8uROqVWIleK4jdK5WALKsQA)